# Hide scrollbar preview

Tags: android, scroll

When you enter the activity for the first time you will see the scrollbar(from `HorizontalScrollView`) for a sec and then it will dim out. Then when you will scroll it will appear again and dim out when you done scrolling.

How to disable this first time scroll preview when you enter the activity, but keep the scroll bar visible during the scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

Found it: it's called setScrollIndicators and it's used as fallow:

```
ViewCompat.setScrollIndicators(yourView, 0);
```

Or for API 23+

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:scrollIndicators="none"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```